# Remove Check box Using Name In Jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

i am using jstree

```
 <div class="demo jstree jstree-0 jstree-default jstree-focused" id="jstree1">
<ul>
    <li id="4331" class="jstree-closed jstree-last jstree-unchecked">
        <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
        <a href="#" class="">
            <ins class="jstree-checkbox" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</ins>
            <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
            T-Shirt
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

tree is like

T-Shirt (Root)

-Solid tees (Child)

-Graphic tees(Child)

-polo tees(Child)

now i want to remove check box in root means `T-shirt`

i can remove checkbox using this code

```
(function(){
  j("#jstree1 li ").filter("#4331").each(function() {j("a ins", this).first().hide();});
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 6);
})();
```

but main problem is that i am removing checkbox using id that is `4331`

when ever i add new category to this tree the ids of all tree are changed

so it is not working

i want to do this code using name `T-Shirt` so when i add new category it will not create problem for me

Comment: try the following 
j("#jstree1 li ").filter("[name=T-Shirt]")

Comment: @Ramesh it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using css to hide chechboxes for "collapsible" items?

`.jstree-closed a .jstree-checkbox, 
.jstree-opened a .jstree-checkbox 
{ display: none; }`

Comment: my question is that i want to hide using name. i know how to hide check box. mine code is working but it is creating a problem when id is changed..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use class to hide checkboxes?

- add class `"attr":{"rel":"directory"}` (see my example below) to the nodes that you don't want the checkbox to have visible.
- then use css `[rel=directory] .jstree-checkbox { display:none }` to hide the checkbox

Check out my jsfiddle where I hide directories. 
http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/68/